# FullStack JS Framework with Live Database data

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a Fullstack JS system that I can use. I really like Meteor for its livequery feature that updates your query data on the web page when there is a change in the database. The problem is that it uses MongoDB which I am unable to use due to requirement constraints. The stack needs to be able to use Oracle or MySQL databases.

I have looked on the internet for a similar system but I am unable to find anything with a similar live update system.

Has anyone got any suggestions?